# Worksheet Range Reference - Expands based on data added/removed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Trying to make an array change based on the length of the data added.  The data has to be deleted except for the top row starting at A:4 and then pulled via a database that creates rows drilling down to the bottom of the node(s).  This can vary from A10:Axxxxx depending on the data in that node.

> `=AVERAGE(IF((MOD(ROW(Repurchase!E4:E45)+4,6)=0)*(Repurchase!E4:E45)<>0,(MOD(ROW(Repurchase!E4:E45)+4,6)=0)*(Repurchase!E4:E45)))`

What I have so far and it works. But of course once the data is deleted and re-pulled

> `Repurchase!#REF!`

shows up and I have to manually add back in A4:Axxxx.

Any help would be appreciated.  Can use VBA if needed but was looking for a non-macro worksheet solution.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a table? This will automatically expand as data is added - just highlight your current data (there should be no blank rows) and press ctrl + T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all references of `Repurchase!E4:E45` with,

```
Repurchase!E4:INDEX(Repurchase!E:E, MATCH(1e99, Repurchase!E:E))
```

This will create a range from E4 down to the last number in column E. You can delete rows without consequence but the range will dynamically reshape to the new proportions. There can be blank or text within the range. It will always be from E4 to the last number in the column.

If someone suggests the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), tell them you would prefer to avoid volatile functions.

If the rows could potentially affect E4 as well, then use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to reference both sides of the colon in the range reference.

```
INDEX(Repurchase!E:E, 4):INDEX(Repurchase!E:E, MATCH(1e99, Repurchase!E:E))
```

Comment: Thanks,  seems to work going down but the E4 seems to change as well.  I'll play around with it and should be able to get the other part working from here.

Comment: You need $E$4, or E$4.

Comment: Even then it replaces the E$4 with #REF.  You would think it would be that simple but for some reason it (Excel) doesn't like it.  Probably something to do with how it pulls the data from the database.  Your part is working like a charm though ;)  Going to try to use E$3 and offset it or add +1...something of that nature as x$3 is a frozen header from there up.

Comment: You *could* take it one step further and use `INDEX(Repurchase!E:E, 4):INDEX(Repurchase!E:E, MATCH(1e99, Repurchase!E:E))`. That puits the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to use for both sides of the colon. If this works, I'll append my response with it.

Comment: Your version works.  I'm also using `OFFSET(Repurchase!E$3,1,0):INDEX(Repurchase!E:E,MATCH(1e99, Repurchase!E:E))` as well; with E$3 being a constant that does not contain data that changes.                         Thanks again :)

Comment: Remember that the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) is considered **volatile**. This means that it will recalculate whenever *anything* in the entire workbook changes, not just when something changes that will affect it. If it recalculates then anything references by it will also recalculate. Avoid its use when a non-volatile solution is available.